# How constraint application / restriction works in haskell?

Tags: haskell

It seems to me that that type annotation and type application play similar role in several context. But there are situation where type application is just not possible and the only way to reproduce its behavior type annotation

```hs
λ> :set -XTypeApplications

λ> :t fromInteger(42::Integer)
fromInteger(42::Integer) :: Num a => a
λ> :t 42
42 :: Num p => p

λ> fromInteger @Float (42::Integer)  
42.0
λ> 42 :: Float
42.0
```

As suggested here https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/ptzzwg/diehls_comments_on_haskell_numbers_confuse/

> For technical reasons we can't write 42 @Float.

My question would then be

If Type Annotation and Type Application are indeed the same as in result in the same effect, what is actually happening when we write

```
λ> 42 :: Fractional a => a
42.0  -- type defaulting is understood and not the issue of the question
λ> :t it
it :: Fractional a => a
```

Does that make sense to say that it is equivalent to

> 42 @Fractional a => a

I find that strange as type application, if my understanding is correct is for concrete type only. Also it seems to me that in fact we are instead adding more constraint to `a` rather than applying a full new type.

Hence the question: What is  actually happening under the hood here ?

Because indeed when i add the constraint manually the following occur (due indeed  to the hierarchy)

```hs
λ> 42 :: (Num a, Fractional a) => a
42.0
λ> :t it
it :: Fractional a => a

λ> :t 42 :: (Num a, Fractional a) => a
42 :: (Num a, Fractional a) => a :: Fractional a => a
```

The point being, that this behavior feels more like what is actually happening when we write `42 :: Fractional a => a` rather than thinking of it as `42 @Fractional a => a`

## EDIT1

Following @leftaroundabout excellent answer i would like to add more context to my question to help narrow down what i am after.

In short, why is it that the following works:

```hs
λ> (2 :: (Num p => p)) :: (Fractional p => p)
2.0
```

But the inverse does not

```
λ> (2 :: (Fractional p => p)) :: (Num p => p)

<interactive>:5:2: error:
    • Could not deduce (Fractional p1)
        arising from an expression type signature
      from the context: Num p
        bound by the inferred type of it :: Num p => p
        at <interactive>:5:1-42
      or from: Num p1
        bound by an expression type signature:
                   forall p1. Num p1 => p1
        at <interactive>:5:31-42
      Possible fix:
        add (Fractional p1) to the context of
          an expression type signature:
            forall p1. Num p1 => p1
    • In the expression: (2 :: (Fractional p => p)) :: (Num p => p)
      In an equation for ‘it’:
          it = (2 :: (Fractional p => p)) :: (Num p => p)
```

I suspect that there must be more to

```
λ> 42 :: Fractional a => a
```

being equivalent

```
it :: ∀ a . Fractional a => a
it = 42
```

The point being that 42 has the polymorphic type derived from  `fromInteger(42::Integer) = Num a => a` and somehow restricting that further to be `Fractional a => a` is ok. The other way around would not work.

**How do that mechanic work, how is it called and what rules does it follow ?**

My original understanding was that type application was happening, but clearly based on @@leftaroundabout answer, I understand now that's not what is happening.

**Reading around i'm suspecting that it is more related to Type Unification ??**

Comment: `Fractional` has a `Num` constraint (it is a “subclass” of `Num`). The opposite is not true. When you try it the “wrong way around,” the `Num` constraint says it can work as *any* `Num` while the `Fractional` constraint says it requires `Fractional` (which contradicts the part that says it can work as *any* `Num`, since not all `Num` types are `Fractional`)

Comment: It might be easier to see if you try this, which has a very similar problem: `(2.0 :: Float) :: Num a => a`  Also you can see the relationship between the two classes [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Fractional)

Comment: Your edit-question is much clearer than the original one, but it's also just _a different question_ so I'd suggest you ask it as such, and remove the added part here.

Comment: the added part ? not sure to follow. You would want me to remove the oiginal question and stick to the Edit1 ? Generally i like immutability, because it is helpful to see how folks progress trough their understanding. It could be useful to anyone going trough  the same journey. But i can do something about it, if it helps getting the right answer.

Comment: @MaatDeamon I would say it would be best to leave the original question as it was originally and move the edit to a new question. StackOverflow is not set up to work well with a "back-and-forth" discussion, involving new questions, within a single "question post." It makes things less organized and can invalidate existing answers. 
 Furthermore, multiple questions within a single "question post" is discouraged. For example, question posts can be closed as "too broad." Also, to me, "immutability" would be to not edit in a new question in the first place.

Comment: Here is why I think there are two distinct questions: (1) The original question is about using constraints in a type application (this does not work, as explained). (2) The new question is about why some expressions of the form `(e :: C1 a => a) :: C2 a => a` type check and others do not. You can always link to the previous question in your new question. This will also automatically create a link going the other direction in the sidebar, as well (under “Linked”). Now the two questions will *still* be linked to each other for anyone looking at them, but it's more organized.

Comment: Understood will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All polymorphic functions/values have implicit extra arguments, specifying what concrete types the type variables in the signature are instantiated to. All a type application does is explicitly pass a type-value into that implicit argument, which otherwise the type checker would try to infer from the context.

What this never does is quantifying over new type variables or applying (non-equational) constraints to them.

It is sensible enough to write `42 @Double`. It happens to be not allowed by Haskell, but it could well be, because the polymorphic literal expects an implicit type argument, and `Double` is a suitable instantiation. (Though of course, why not just write `42 :: Double` instead!) In particular, `Double` has kind `Type`, and it has a `Num` instance.

`42 @Fractional` however doesn't make sense, because `Fractional` is a type class, i.e. it has kind `Type -> Constraint`, and a number literal doesn't accept anything like that. When you write `42 :: Fractional a => a`, what you're doing instead is to (anonymously) define a *new* polymorphic value. Your GHCi request is shorthand for making a definition

```
it :: ∀ a . Fractional a => a
it = 42
```

You could *then* afterwards write `it @Double` or `it @Rational` (but not `it @Int`).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. On `42 :: Fractional a => a` i can't help it but feel like it is just half of the story. More specifically why is it that this is ok `(2 :: (Num p => p)) :: (Fractional p => p)` but the inverse `(2 :: (Fractional p => p)) :: (Num p => p)` is not ok ?

Comment: Will update the question and add the error.

Comment: Accepted the answer, given that it is correct with respect to how the question was originally articulated. I will open another question with the Edit that focus on the subject of what's the mechanic behind the ability in haskell to assign a more specific type to a value of a more generic type, or how we can further qualify the type of a value. This is what i concluded my original question subject was fundamentally about and should have been formulated around.

Comment: you actually gloss over it when you  say `What this never does is quantifying over new type variables or applying (non-equational) constraints to them.`

Comment: So yes it is not `Type Application` that is happening. But i am not convinced about `(anonymously) define a new polymorphic value.` Because otherwise as i  stated above  `(2 :: (Fractional p => p)) :: (Num p => p)` would work. Unless i missunderstand your statement, and by a new value, you meant a new binding, as in a new variable. I blieve the Value stays the same, it is just qualified further according to the annotation, and GHC check that this qualification make sense & even clean it up when there is redundancy. So I would say that it is something akin to `Type Qualification is happening`

Comment: However I don't know the inferencing system enough so let's probably get to it in another question :) better formulated.